# All PHP files slow - no server load

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using Nginx + PHP5-FPM and all PHP files loaded over port 80 are extremely slow - they take several minutes to load, even a simple phpinfo file.

php -i over shell is lightning quick, and the server itself is pretty powerful and has a very low load.

I've also tried Apache and Litespeed with the same results as Nginx. Flat HTML fiLes are also very quick.

This has been happening since a power outage and a hard reboot.

Has anyone got any ideas why this server could be so slow at processing PHP files?

Comment: Are you using any special settings for sessions or file prepend?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: same thing with me, phpinfo script served by Apache is super slow, but `php -i` is very fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one isn't easy to diagnose, but the best way to do it if you have made NO changes to the stock php.ini file is to run strace against one of the child php fpm processes.

First reduce the max/min/start  number of FPM children down to 1 and restart FPM.

Grab the PID of the FPM Child process and run `strace -p PID` as root.

Then hit the slow PHP page with your browser and watch the strace output to see where you process is hanging. It'll give you all the system calls made by PHP and you can see if its doing something stupid.

Comment: This is basically what I've been trying to do. It seems to hang after the last line here every time, but I'm not sure how to make sense of this: `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 9
fcntl(9, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(9, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("66.199.138.142")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 60000 <unfinished ...>`

Comment: It is opening a socket, assigning 9 as the file handle, then connecting it to port 80 on 66.199.138.142. It then waits until that connection times out and returns.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually consistent with a lot of SYN_SENT requests shown on lsof -i :80, so I'm guessing that it's waiting for something from the server at 66.199.138.142? Any ideas how I can check for what, or why it may be impacting on simple phpinfo files? The IP and IP Whois don't really ring any bells

Comment: Is there any indication where in the execution that happens? Is it right after reading the PHP file?

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: Early on you'll see a stat() of a path for your php file, followed by an open() of that file and finally a read() of the file handle. Thats the point where it loads your PHP file.

Comment: I took a look at your pastebin, but I couldn't figure out where it was pausing. Could you post another pastebin strace that loads a phpinfo() page?

Comment: Check your php.ini file for an auto-prepend if your code is not connecting to this address / capture the traffic with wireshark to see what it's fetching

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but you might want to install [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) and have a look at where the execution hangs, it might at least give you an *hint* as to the source of the problem, given that it's not immediately apparent.

[image: webgrind screenshot]